# how to update stdscr size with python curses after resizing the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, curses, windows-terminal, python-curses

I tried searching everywhere on the internet, but nowhere did I find an answer that worked for me, so I'm asking a new question.

In my code, I'm telling curses to get the terminal size and update some variables according to it. On my first try, I did something like this (this is the function that gets called after the window has been resized manually):

```
def resize():
    rows, cols = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    #some more code irrelevant to the question
```

When I found out that doesn't work, I realised that the stdscr is probably not getting resized, even though the terminal is. So I tried closing the stdscr and initialising it again:

```
def resize():
    curses.endwin()
    curses.wrapper(initialise)
    #some more code that's irrelevant to the question

#showing the initialise function just in case:
def initialise(stdscrarg):
    global stdscr
    stdscr = stdscrarg
```

That, however, also didn't work. In other words, the stdscr initialised in the size that the terminal had before resizing. i.e. if I had a terminal over a quarter of my screen and then resized it to full screen, the function would correctly deal with the warping of the text, but it would redraw the content adjusted to just the original quarter of the screen, and would leave the junk characters in the rest of the screen, like this:
[image: Picture before resizing]
Before resizing

[image: Picture after resizing, before refreshing]
After resizing, before refreshing

[image: Picture after refreshing]
After refreshing.

As you can see, the stdscr has initialised to its original size instead of taking on the size of the terminal. And I have tested it and confirmed that it really is the size of the stdscr, and not just the text printed on it (as when I gradually add strings to it, it throws an error when it reaches the end of the original size screen, instead of continuing to the end of the terminal screen and only then throwing an error.)

My question is: How can I get the new size of the terminal and make stdscr initialise with this new size?

Working on Windows 11, Python 3.10, module curses (though when installing it through pip, its name is windows-curses)

Comment: You have this tagged [tag:windows-terminal], but the screenshots show that you are using the legacy Windows Console Host, not Windows Terminal.  You might try installing Windows Terminal from the Microsoft Store.  It may or may not fix your problem, but it is Microsoft's new, modern, actively-developed, open-source replacement terminal, so it's a good idea to upgrade regardless.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thank you, but even when I opened it with the Windows PowerShell Terminal, it had absolutely no effect - the stdscr still doesn't update its size according to the terminal. It now only looks uglier.

Comment: It's possibly the [bug in python packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520435/key-resize-not-returned-from-getch-when-xterm-is-resized) previously noted.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Neat, thanks, though I'm not importing readlines. The only other module I'm importing is keyboard, and the functionality which this question concerns didn't work even before I imported it.

I'm also not using the getch() method to recognised when the terminal has been resized, I have the user do that manually by pressing a key.

Though from what I understand now, it's a bug and it's probably not going to be fixable by me, am I getting it right?